# Variable inside of array not working?

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to retreive some information outside of an array I have created inside of a loop.

If I hard code the array location things print out as expected. If I add the variable inside of the loop to print each array, I get nothing.

```
$num = 0;
  foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) {
    $num++;
    $field_playback_format = $field['playback_format'];
    print_r($field_playback_format[$num]);
  }
```

Prints nothing. But if I replace $num with a value, say 1, things echo onto the screen.

But if I do:

```
$num = 0;
  foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) {
    $num++;
    $field_playback_format = $field['playback_format'];
    print_r($field_playback_format[1]);
  }
```

This works as expected and prints out what I need. The reason I need to do this inside of a loop is because I have constructed multiple arrays `$field_playback_format[1]` and `$field_playback_format[2]` contain different values, but I need to retrieve them both inside the loop.

Am I not able to use a variable in this spot??

Answer (score 0):

Array starts from 0, your script increment immediately the index and you have an error because the last loop try to get an element of array that doesn't exist because the index is +1 than the real value.
try this:

```
$num = 0;
  foreach ( $repeatable_fields as $field ) {
    $field_playback_format = $field['playback_format'];
    print_r($field_playback_format[$num]);
    $num++;
  }
```

Your second script works because you print an existing element. But if you try to print with a major index retrieve an error and you can't see the print_r

Comment: This would make sense if you knew $field['playback_format'] was an array with a 0 index, or if the assign was like this: $field_playback_format[] = $field['playback_format'];  Otherwise, I don't see this helping much.

Comment: array starts from 0 normally in php @Rob

Comment: true, but when you have an array with an index of 'playback_format' it doesn't make sense to assume all indexes start with 0.

Comment: I will try this out when I get back into work tomorrow. This problem has been hounding me for a few days, and I think I'm finally about to crack it. Will report back tomorrow morning!

Comment: hmmm still facing an issue. It seems to be looping through and storing one value. The rest are stored as null. This damn radio button issue is plaguing me!